# How can I adjust the width of a nested div to equal the width of an ancestor div?

Tags: css, position

My pages are structured as nested divs. They have padding and margin so inner divs are typically physically smaller than outer divs. However, in some cases I would like one of the inner divs (red box in the image below) to expand widthwise to match the left and right edges of the outermost div.

[image: nested divs]

```
<div id="div-a">
  <div id="div-b">
    <div id="div-c">
      <div id="div-d">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is just an example -- the number of nested divs can vary. The width of the outermost div is variable. The heights of all the divs are also variable.

I have tried using absolute positioning, but this removes div-d from the document flow. Since I don't know the height of its content, I can't compensate. Any other suggestions? Thank you for any help.

```
#div-a {
  position:relative;
}
#div-d {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: do you want only div-d to expand and match parent width ?

Comment: @Arun it could be any (or more than one) of the inner divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I could not find a CSS-only solution for my particular problem. I had to resort to Javascript.

1. wrap the div that needs to be full-width with another div

```
<div id="div-a">
  <div id="div-b">
    <div id="div-c">
      <div id="div-d-wrapper">
      <div id="div-d">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. use this CSS

```
#div-a {
  position:relative;
}
#div-d {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

3. apply the following Javascript (using jQuery)

```
$('#div-d-wrapper').height($('#div-d').outerHeight());
```

Answer (score 1):

Could this approach be a solution?

```
#div-c {
position:relative;
}
#div-d {
position:absolute;
padding:0 -(div-c + div-b + div-a padding values) 0 -(div-c + div-b + div-a padding 
values)}
```

Comment: I've considered this, but the width of the div padding changes responsively, so I won't know the total width as the page is being generated.

Answer (score 1):

```
#div-c {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#div-d {
    width: calc(100% + PADDINGS + BORDERS);
}
```

PADDINGS: sum of each parents divs padding.

BORDERS: sum of each parents borders.

Comment: I've considered this, but the padding changes responsively, so I won't know the total width when the page is being generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
  padding:10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#div-d{
  margin-left:-32px;
  margin-right:-32px;
}
```

i used hard code values to for the given div . My solution is to use Negative margins in css. When the div grows dynamically, you use javascript or jquery to find parent reach from child div and calculate the margins accordingly.

fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bqrxtLvd/

Source:
[Negative margin css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/negative-margins/)

[Detailed negative margin](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2020/02/negative_margin.html)